# SQL Query to fill ALL VALUES in a SINGLE column

Tags: sql, postgresql

This may sound basic and often asked, but I'm surprised how often this question is just partially answered.

Assume I have  a POSTGRESQL db which has table with a column called "calculation" in a table called "table". This column is currently filled with NULL.

I have all values to fill calculation outside the database. Imagine the values are in a string separated by commas. Now I with to construct an SQL statement that changes ALL values of "calculation", in the order they appear in such a string.

Similar questions here have been asked, and there an infinite amount of tutorials on the internet on how to add values to a database,  but they always suggest:

```
UPDATE calculation FROM table SET calculation=value WHERE ...
```

The problems with that command is that: (1) it requires a WHERE conditions, which does not exist (we want to update all values not only values that fit a specific condition). (2) Assumes there is only one value for calculation. Thus, it seems to suggest that we have to call one query for every single line.

People asking often gravitate to:

```
INSERT INTO table (calculation) VALUES ...
```

which fits the syntax perfectly, but does not work because the column is already there and the rows are already create.

This is a straightforward operation outside SQL. R,python,matlab, and other languages often have the ability to append vectors as columns to their table-equivalents. Or, even better, replace contents of a column by a vector. What am I missing?

EDIT: A MORE CONCRETE EXAMPLE:

Assume the following table already exist in database db, with name "table"

| PKID | name | calculation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | alfa | NULL |
| 2 | beta | NULL |
| 3 | theta | NULL |

I wish to fill the calculation field with values "akdak","dndja" and "jsnajsna", respectively. Such that:

| PKID | name | calculation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | alfa | akdak |
| 2 | beta | dndja |
| 3 | theta | jsnajsna |

How can I do that in a single sql query without referencing PKID and name values in a WHERE clause?

Comment: you are missing sample data and desired output

Comment: Short answer: do an update without a `WHERE`. Long answer: you must add details to your question for it to be answered. In SQL, it makes little sense to speak about the order of records without specifying columns used to sort them. You can only rely on logical ordering for your queries, not how they are physically stored (which may change without your control). And that is without mentionning a comma-separated string may not match the number of records in your table either. Even if you check it matches before updating, it may have already changed, by another user, when you proceed.

Comment: I think your statement about SQL is the answer. But I will give an more complete example, for the sake of the clarity

Comment: Example added as requested

Comment: This doesn't store a value in all rows, it calculates a value using some unknown formula. Where do these numbers come from? Is it the row number based on some ordering? A copy of the PK? Something else? Why *not* use `UPDATE calulation FROM table SET calculation=PKID` ?

Comment: Sorry, I something must have been missed in my explanation. Assume there are ONLY 3 rows in this table. To shed away any calculation complication, assume that calculation was NULL and I woke up today and decided to fill it with numbers 1,2 and 3. How to do it?

Comment: To make the problem more real. I have a really complex script that output a character vector (a representation of an R language object). This script takes as input the names in column name. However, for the sake of speed in the script, it makes sense to donwload all names with `SELECT name FROM table` ,run my script, and get a list of values to be inserted/uploaded in calculation. Much like I took the input together in a single query it make sense to insert/upload the output in a single query

Comment: Don't ask people to assume or give examples of how you'd solve the problem in another language. What *is* the problem in the first place?  Edit the question and explain where those numbers come from. For example, you can calculate row numbers, ranks, percentiles with ranking functions like `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SomeField)`. SQL queries aren't scripts, they're a description of the set-based logic. It's up to the server to come up with an efficient execution strategy. If you have indexes, the query will be fast. If not, it will be slow.

Comment: SQL deals with sets, not vectors. There's no row order in a set, not even a physical storage order. If the server uses parallel execution in a query the results may come in any order. If you want to store specific values in specific records you *must* specify the primary key.

Comment: I see, so the answer is "you can't". But just to adress, your previous comment. I'm asking people to assume because the calculation is not relevant. I regret even using this term now, as it clearly confused the question. The minimum reproducible example is as stated. I have a set of values say "akdak","dndja","jsnajsna". It does not matter their origin. The output of SELECT * FROM table is as indicated in the first table. I with, with a single UPDATE command, to set  the value of row 1 to "akdak", the value of row 2 as "dndja" and the value of row 3 "jsnajsna".

Comment: So the first value, in alphabetical order, in column `name` (`alpha`) gets the first value, also in alphabetical order, from your list of values (`akdak`)? The second value in `name` gets the second value in your list, and so on?

Comment: Yes, thanks! Exactly! To make it even more clear, the first value of name (`alpha`) gets the first value of the list (`akdak`), the second value in name (`beta`) gets the second value of the list `dndja`, the third value of name (`theta`) gets the third value `jsnajsna`.

Comment: For even more emphasis, now informed by Panagiotis. The alphabetical order works, but so would the numerical order of PKID. The important concept is how to UPDATE an entire column in a single call, without having to keep using different WHERE clauses for each row.

Comment: @JMenezes no, the answer is `what is the question and why don't you use the PKs`? Even if you want to send the data as a batch, using the PK values is a *lot* easier, safer and faster than trying to guess which records to update

Comment: `so would the numerical order of PKID` you don't need to order the IDs. You can use them to join the result rows with the table rows unambiguously. There's no reason to put multiple IDs in WHERE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to execute something that makes use of the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to create a correspondance, based on an order, between records:

```
WITH ValueList(Calculation) AS (
    Values('akdak'),('dndja'),('jsnajna')
)
UPDATE MyTable
SET Calculation = V.Calculation
FROM (
    SELECT Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Name)
    FROM MyTable
) T(Name, rownum)
JOIN (
    SELECT Calculation, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Calculation)
    FROM ValueList
) V(Calculation, rownum)
ON T.rownum = V.rownum
WHERE MyTable.Name = T.Name
```

The `JOIN` will make it so the value count does not need to match the records in the table. Extra values will be ignored, the `calculation` column of extra record will remain null.

Note: I have put `WHERE MyTable.Name = T.Name` at the end of the query but depending of which columns are `UNIQUE` and/or `NOT NULL` and what precise behavior you want, you may prefer to use `WHERE MyTable.PKID = T.PKID`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will update the question so the values are not 1,2,3 and match the answer, for posterity!

Comment: Why not use the primary key values instead of trying to re-create them? This `UPDATE` would work better and faser if the `VALUES` constructor included the PK values instead of waiting for `ROW_NUMBER` to create them. Besides, nothing guarantees that the data was loaded ordered by `Name`

Comment: The point I was making in my comments right under the question was to sort records in a logical order, i.e. based on the values in a column. By nature, a primary key is used only to reference every record uniquely; it is not supposed to be given a meaning. With that said, it is not a complete non sense to use `PKID` to artificially create an order either, so I added a note about it.

Comment: Regarding the order the data was loaded to the table, it is not accessible. The best you can use is the order records are physically stored in, which can be the same but can also be different (e.g. with bulk `INSERT`, `DELETE`, `VACUUM`, `INSERT`). You can use an `inserted_ts` column to store the timestamp of every insertion in the table but using it bring you back to a logical order (since it is a column in the table).

Answer (score -1):

Based on the accepted answer it seems the real question is how to perform a batch update with a single query.

For lots of data (thousands or more), the typical solution is to insert the data into a staging table with eg `COPY` and then update the target table by JOINing on the ID values. Since primary keys are indexed, the JOIN will be fast:

```
UPDATE Target
Set 
   Calculation1=staging.Calculation1,
   ...
FROM Source INNER JOIN Target
    ON Source.ID=Target.ID
```

For a smaller number of rows a table value constructor can be used to emit the ID and new values :

```
UPDATE Target
Set 
   Calculation1=staging.Calculation1,
   ...
FROM (
        VALUES
        (1, 'London'),
        (2, 'Rio de Janeiro'),
        (3, 'Tokyo')
     ) as Source(ID, Field1) 
INNER JOIN Target
    ON Source.ID=Target.ID;
```